# xUnit fixtures classes for internal types

Tags: c#, xunit, fixtures

When unit testing classes with the `internal` access modifier, I can add the following to the `.csproj` file of the project under test:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <InternalsVisibleTo Include="[test_project_name]"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works fine for any internal types in the original project, when they are being instantiated as private members of the test class, or as local variables in any of the test methods.

However, it can't work when trying to use them with fixtures, because these types need to be made public members of a public fixture class.

Is there a code pattern that allows me to declare my fixtures as internal?

Comment: _"When unit testing classes with the internal access modifier"_ - a better way to deal with this issue is to make `public` types that wrap those `internal` types.

Comment: That replicates the limitations of the fixture class. I can't cross assembly boundaries with internal types. A public type wrapper in the test project will not compile.

Comment: "A public type wrapper in the test project will not compile. " - put it in the main project assembly, perhaps in a namespace named `InternalForTesting` or similar - also, what about `InternalsVisibleTo`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-6.0

Comment: I specifically mention `InternalsVisibleTo` in my question. It doesn't answer the problem because it is meant to bring those types into the visible scope of the test project, not to expose them as public members of that assembly. Not sure why would someone downvote my question...

Comment: Probably because there is a lot of dogma about only unit testing public methods. (As though private and internal methods don't have a contract and don't need to work properly)

Comment: After some more digging, I came to realize this is just not possible. The `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute has its uses. But when it comes to unit testing it is nothing more than a hack. The obvious limitation is that I won't be able to turn an internal class in one assembly into a public class in another. This would break basic access rules. And it's not even clear to me at this point that xUnit could offer internal fixtures. These wouldn't be visible to the test runner assemblies.